# Работа с функциями

Tags: c++, функции, проверка

Есть функция удаления динамических компонентов:

```
void clear()
{
  Button1->Free();
  Button2->Free();
  Button3->Free();
  Button4->Free();
  Button5->Free();
  Button6->Free();
  Button7->Free();
  Memo1->Free();
  Memo2->Free();
  Label1->Free();
  Label2->Free();
  Label3->Free();
  Edit1->Free();
  Edit2->Free();
  Edit3->Free();
  Edit4->Free();
  UpDown1->Free();
  UpDown2->Free();
  UpDown3->Free();
}
```

Есть функция создания:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::N3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  if(nq>=1)
  {
    clear();
  }
  creint();
  Edit1->Free();
  Edit2->Free();
  Edit3->Free();
  Edit4->Free();
  UpDown1->Free();
  UpDown2->Free();
  UpDown3->Free();
  Button5->Free();
  Button6->Free();
  Button7->Free();
  Memo2->Free();
  Label3->Free();
}
```

Но перед функцией создания `creint()` идет функция `clear()`.
И соответственно выходит ошибка, так как функция `clear()` удаляет все компоненты которые были. А я удаляю заранее некоторые, так как они не нужны.

Вопрос как этого избежать? Или сделать какое-нибудь небольшое условие на проверку компонентов на форме?

Comment: А Вы обнуляете указатели после удаления?

Comment: Не знаю, создаю и удаляю, какое обнуление нужно?

Comment: Вот так создаю.

Comment: Обязательно нужно делать так: обьявление SomeClass *p_Class=0; создание p_Class=new SomeClass(...); Создание можно объединить с объявлением. Удаление delete p_Class; p_Class = 0; А еще лучше использовать умные указатели.

Comment: Повторное применение delete приводит к краху программы, но этого не происходит если указателю было присвоено нулевое значение.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что за белиберда? Ваша функция "создания" бесконечно рекурсивно вызывает сама себя, а также как будто пытается заниматься почти тем же самым удалением, что и функция "удаления". Что это и к чему это - не ясно.

Comment: По клику создается, белиберды нету, просто я не стал все писать досканально, вопрос есть, нужна помощь, а не глупые комментарии вроде этого

Comment: Просьбы о помощи должны сопровождаться вменяемым описанием проблемы, а не истеричным воем с заламыванием рук. Вам указано на явный объективный бред в вашей постановке вопроса. Когда вам указывают на откровенный бред в вашей постановке вопроса, вы быстренько прекращаете разглагольствовать, а занимаетесь исправлением указанных проблем. Вопросы есть? Вопросов нет. Вперед выполнять! Давать оценки чужим комментариям - запрещаю.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object *obj = new Object();
if (obj != NULL)
    std::cout << "Объект не удалён!";
else 
    std::cout << "Объект удалён или не инициализирован!";
```

После удаления нужно так же обнулить переменную:

```
obj = NULL;
```

Comment: `new` кидает исключение, если при выделении памяти произошла ошибка.